# Login with beautiful soup 4 on Tick Tick

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, webrequest

I am trying to make an API that can web scape off Tick Tick - https://ticktick.com/signin, on python. I tried using beautiful soup, but I had no luck. Could someone please help me to log into this website with python.

Answer (score 0):

For any type of scraping that requires you to load JS or to interact with the webpages, I recommend you to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html).